# Trying to count words, only counts last list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count, cpu-word

```python
for tekst in textblock:
    woorden_tekst = tekst.get_text()
    woorden_lib = woorden_tekst.split()
    print(woorden_lib)
    # see the result
    ## hier begint de dict.
    for woord in woorden_lib:
        if woord in counts:
            counts[woord] = +1
        else:
            counts[woord] = 1
    ###print(counts)
```

Here is the result:

```python
['Een', 'groep', 'van', 'zestien', 'burgers', 'heeft', 'de', 'overheid', 'voor', 'de', 'rechter', 'gedaagd', 'vanwege', 'de', 'stank', 'die', 'wordt', 'veroorzaakt', 'door', 'megastallen.', 'Het', 'gaat', 'om', 'twaalf', 'mensen', 'uit', 'Noord-Brabant,', 'twee', 'inwoners', 'van', 'Limburg,', 'een', 'inwoner', 'van', 'Gelderland', 'en', 'een', 'inwoner', 'van', 'Overijssel.', 'Zij', 'zeggen', 'dat', 'veel', 'burgers', 'op', 'het', 'platteland', '"voortdurend', 'last', 'hebben', 'van', 'een', 'overdosis', 'stank"', 'en', 'willen', 'beter', 'beschermd', 'worden.']
['De', 'burgers', 'werken', 'samen', 'met', 'het', 'Brabants', 'Burgerplatform,', 'een', 'beweging', 'die', 'opkomt', 'voor', '"verontruste', 'bewoners', 'van', 'het', 'platteland".', 'In', 'een', 'verklaring', 'zegt', 'het', 'platform', 'dat', 'de', 'veehouderij', 'op', 'dit', 'moment', 'te', 'veel', 'wordt', 'beschermd.', '"Door', 'de', 'uitzonderingen', 'in', 'de', 'wet', 'en', 'de', 'overmatige', 'bescherming', 'van', 'eerder', 'door', 'veehouders', 'verworven', 'rechten', 'wordt', 'er', 'zoveel', 'hinder', 'toegestaan,', 'dat', 'het', 'recht', 'op', 'ongestoord', 'woongenot', 'van', 'burgers', 'wordt', 'geschonden."']
['Volgens', 'de', 'groep', 'schendt', 'de', 'overheid', 'het', 'Europees', 'Verdrag', 'voor', 'de', 'Rechten', 'van', 'de', 'Mens,', 'de', 'Grondwet', 'en', 'het', 'Burgerlijk', 'Wetboek,', 'doordat', 'de', 'Staat', 'het', 'woongenot', 'naar', 'hun', 'mening', 'niet', 'beschermt.', 'Ze', 'verwijzen', 'in', 'hun', 'dagvaarding', 'naar', 'zestien', 'varkens-', 'rundvee-', 'en', 'pluimveehouderijen.']
['Het', 'Brabants', 'Burgerplatform', 'denkt', 'dat', 'er', 'een', 're�le', 'kans', 'is', 'op', 'succes', 'bij', 'de', 'rechter.', '"De', 'Staat', 'werd', 'al', 'eerder', 'op', 'de', 'vingers', 'getikt', 'in', 'een', 'vergelijkbare', 'kwestie:', 'de', 'Urgenda-zaak",', 'meldt', 'het', 'platform.', '"Ook', 'hier', 'ging', 'het', 'om', 'onvoldoende', 'bescherming', 'van', 'burgers,', 'tegen', 'klimaatverandering,', 'en', 'schending', 'door', 'de', 'Staat', 'van', 'het', 'Europees', 'Verdrag', 'voor', 'de', 'Rechten', 'van', 'de', 'Mens."']
```

I am trying to count the word on a page. I managed to get the text and split the text. But then I try to count with

```python
for woord in woorden_lib:
    if woord in counts:
        counts[woord] = +1
    else:
        counts[woord] = 1
    ###print(counts)
```

I only counts the last list, but it has to count in all the lists of course. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change counts[woord] = +1 to counts[woord]  += 1.... maybe just a typo?

Comment: Also check https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: what is `woorden_lib` and `counts`?

Comment: I used counter - from collections import Counter counts = Counter(woorden_lib)
print(counts)  - thanks that worked.